# Mistake in eq. (10.7.19) Weinberg Vol I?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, normalization, textbook-erratum

In Weinberg Vol I, he writes in equation 10.7.19,
$$
\left\langle 0 | \phi (0) | {\mathbf{k}} \right\rangle = ( 2\pi ) ^{ - 3/2} \left( 2 \sqrt{ {\mathbf{k}} ^2 + m ^2 } \right) ^{ - 1/2} N,
\tag{10.7.19}$$
where $\phi $ is a unrenormalized scalar field, $ \left| {\mathbf{k}}  \right\rangle $ is a one-particle state, and $ N $ is some constant. The $ {\mathbf{k}} $ dependence seems wrong. For one thing, this is often taken as the renormalization condition and set equal to $ 1 $. Furthermore, its easy to show the braket should be $ {\mathbf{k}} $-independent by performing a Lorentz transform:
\begin{align*} 
 \left\langle 0 | \phi (0) | {\mathbf{k}} \right\rangle & = \left\langle 0 | U ( \Lambda ) ^\dagger  \phi (0) U ( \Lambda )    |  {\mathbf{k}} \right\rangle \\
  &  = \left\langle 0 |   \phi (0)   | \Lambda {\mathbf{k}} \right\rangle
\end{align*}
Since I am free to choose $ \Lambda $ as I please, the result can't be dependent on $ {\mathbf{k}} $. Is this a mistake or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Possibly related [343516](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/343516/getting-particles-from-fields-normalization-issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is you are taking the inner product to be Lorentz Invariant.  In Weinberg's convention the inner products are not Lorentz Invariante, see Eqn. 2.5.19.  For a covariant normalization the $\sqrt{2E}$ factor would be absent and your argument would go through.