# Local fields in relativity with pure creation operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, non-locality

The Wikipedia page on the [Spin-Statistics theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem) states that

> In relativity, there are no local fields that are pure creation operators or annihilation operators.

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/472406/177077) at SE Phys, in a different context, it is stated

> [...] express a given field operator as a sum of positive- and negative-frequency terms, called creation and annihilation operators. (These operators are necessarily non-local in space.)

Why are creation and annihilation operators necessarily non local in space in QFT?

In condensed matter we routinely use operators like $c^\dagger(x)$ which create particles at a point in space. Why does this break down when we move to a relativistic theory?

Comment: The linked answer mentions the Reeh-Schleider theorem

Comment: It does, but I found the Wikipedia page on the theorem hard to understand and I could not see the relation to the creation operators.