# Interpretation of annihilation and creation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, fourier-transform

If we write some quantum field in a form using creation and annihilation operators we are, in a way, doing a Fourier series with annihilation and creation operators being coefficients. So, if they are a coefficients shouldn't they have some structure? I mean if I do a Fourier series of some function I expect that coefficients also look like functions in k-space. So, what do these operators have besides commutation relations to define the structure of the field?

Comment: They not really the coefficients though. If you write a field in terms of these operators the coefficients are the first quantized wave functions.

Comment: 2nd quantization is after all is said and done, about promoting Fourier/ Sturm-Liouville coefficients in some complete basis, to fully-fledged operators

Comment: But what is the difference between one scalar field and another if we write them both in terms of these operators? I dont see how would we differentiate between fields. Jan Bos, can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/343516/getting-particles-from-fields-normalization-issue-or-localization-issue) might help. Every field *φ(x)* acting on the vacuum is a bit like a wavepacket, with a corresponding wavefunction. You'd normally consider just plane waves for the free field, but sticking a *k*-dependent profile coefficient in the *k*-integral will give you a different field with a different wavepacket profile/wavefunction.