# How can $⟨0|ϕ(x)|p⟩=e^{ip⋅x}$ be mathematically shown?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, klein-gordon-equation

I was reading Peskin and Schroeder's quantum field theory and going through the book mathematically. Then I got stuck at one equation.

Consider a single, non-interacting real scalar field. The book shows that

$$⟨0|ϕ(x)|p⟩=e^{ip⋅x}$$

Which can be interpreted as the position space wavefunction of a single particle state with momentum p (page 24)

and $ϕ(x)$ equals 
$$ϕ(x)=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2w_\mathbf{p}}}(a_\mathbf{p}+a^\dagger_\mathbf{p})e^{ip⋅x}$$

and when $ϕ(x)$ acts on $|0⟩$

$$ϕ(x)|0⟩=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2E_p}e^{-ip⋅x}|\mathbf p⟩$$

How can the following be mathematically shown? 
  $$⟨0|ϕ(x)|p⟩=e^{ip⋅x}$$

Comment: Write $|p\rangle$ in terms of $|0\rangle$ and $a^\dagger$, then use the commutators, with a goal of moving all of the $a^\dagger$s to the left of the $a$s because $\langle 0| a^\dagger a |0\rangle = 0$.

Comment: Possibly [linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/343516/getting-particles-from-fields-normalization-issue-or-localization-issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $$ϕ(x)=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_\mathbf{p}}}(a_\mathbf{p}+a^\dagger_\mathbf{p})e^{ip⋅x} ~,$$
consider the hermitean dual of your third  equation (2.41),
$$\langle 0| ϕ(x)=\int \frac{d^3p'}{(2\pi)^3}    \frac{1}{2E_{p'}}e^{ip'⋅x} \langle \mathbf p' | ~,$$
so that P&S (2.42) trivially follows, by virtue of the peculiar normalization (2.36), a mainstay convention of QFT, 
$$⟨0|ϕ(x)|p⟩=\int \frac{d^3p'}{(2\pi)^3}    \frac{1}{2E_{p'}}e^{ip'⋅x} \langle \mathbf p' |\mathbf p\rangle  \\  =\int \frac{d^3p'}{(2\pi)^3}    \frac{1}{2E_{p'}}e^{ip'⋅x} ~~2E_{p'} (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf {p'-p})= e^{ip⋅x}~.$$

Important: note this state is not fully localized in space, as you might well slip into assuming. Dotting it onto itself it yields *a sharply peaked function*, but not quite a delta function, as detailed in the linked question.