# Physical Interpretation of Field Operator in Quantum Field Theory and Mode Expansion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

I'm struggling to understand the physical interpretation behind the field operators $ \phi(\mathbf x)$  and $\phi ^\dagger (\mathbf x)$ in quantum field theory. My understanding is $ \phi ^\dagger  (\mathbf x)$ is an operator which creates a particle at a position $\mathbf x$. p37 of *Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur* (Lancaster & Blundell, OUP) says that from this definition of $\phi ^\dagger (\mathbf x)$, we can then write
$$ \phi ^\dagger (\mathbf x) \propto \sum_{\mathbf{p}}  a_{\mathbf p}^\dagger e^{-i \mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x}.$$
However this is different to the approach in Peskin & Schroeder. They write out the mode expansion for $\phi(\mathbf x)$ for the Klein-Gordon field (eqn 2.25) as
$$\phi(\mathbf x) \propto \int \frac{1}{\left ( |\mathbf p|^2 + m^2 \right )^{1/4}} \left ( a_{\mathbf p} e^{i \mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x} + a_{\mathbf p} ^\dagger e^{-i \mathbf p \cdot \mathbf x} \right )  d^3 p.$$
I understand that we have two terms since we require $\phi(\mathbf x)$ to be Hermitian. However does this not contradict the definition that $\phi^\dagger (\mathbf x)$ creates a particle at a position $\mathbf x$ above? Is it correct to interpret $\phi(\mathbf x)$ as an operator that creates a particle at $\mathbf x$, or is it better to just ignore the interpretation and only think about the results the theory gives from performing measurements?

Comment: Your second equation is inaccurately copied from P&S (2.25):  it has a $(|{\mathbf p}|^2+ m^2 )^{1/4}$ in the denominator, delocalizing the particle created by the second term, only. See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/343516/getting-particles-from-fields-normalization-issue-or-localization-issue). The first term destroys a particle!

Comment: @NiharKarve my bad - I forgot to add a dagger on the RHS

Comment: Also see Problem 2.3 in L&B - the mode expansion for $\phi$ is analogous to the $\hat{x}$ operator

Answer (score 1):

One could define the field operator either way. The representation with only creation/annihilation operator
$$
\psi(x) \sim \sum_k a_ke^{ikx}, \psi^\dagger(x) \sim \sum_k a_k^\dagger e^{-ikx}
$$
has the interpretation of creating/removing a particle at a particular time point, which is a convenient interpretation, e.g., for electrons. Representations with sum or difference of creating and annihilation operators
$$
\psi(x)\sim \sum(b_k e^{ikx} + b_k^\dagger e^{-ikx}),\\
\psi(x)\sim \sum i(b_k e^{ikx} - b_k^\dagger e^{-ikx})
$$
are more convenient for bosonic fields, where in classical limit they reduce to the field strength (e.g., $E(x,t)$ for the electric field or polarization for phonons).