# What are the momentum states in the second quantization of a free field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, second-quantization

I am reading through Schwartz, and have become quite confused by his discussion of second quantization of a free field (Section 2.3, page 20-21).

To be clear, I think I understand second quantization in general, for instance as described by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization). Here, a basis of states is agreed upon beforehand, then creation and annihilation operators are *defined* as those operators which raise the occupation number of a given basis state by 1, in a symmetrized/antisymmetrized way (which implies the well-known commutation relations for creation/annihilation operators).

In Schwartz, however, it seems the creation operators $a_p^{\dagger}$ and the associated basis states $|p\rangle$ are defined simultaneously. More precisely, inspired by the form of the solution in classical field theory, Schwartz defines the free field Hamiltonian $$H_0 = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\omega_p(a_p^{\dagger}a_p + \frac{1}{2}V),$$ in terms of creation and annihilation operators $a_p^{\dagger}$ and $a_p$ for each $\vec{p}$. But as far as I can tell, he never actually specifies what the state created by $a_p^{\dagger}$, $|p\rangle = \sqrt{2\omega_p}a_p^{\dagger}|0\rangle$, is. He calls these states "momentum" states (again, I assume, inspired by the classical field theory case), but this is far from a definition: at this point in the book, no momentum operator has been defined on Fock space, so I don't know what it means for a quantum state to have momentum $\vec{p}$ (of course I know what this means in single-particle quantum mechanics, but is it really well-defined to define a state in Fock space in terms of a state in the Hilbert space of single-particle quantum mechanics?).

So my question is: What is the defining property that Schwartz has in mind when he declares a single-particle state $|p\rangle$ to have a momentum $\vec{p}$?

(One potentially related piece of the puzzle is that on the following page, Schwartz defines the $\hat{\phi_0}(\vec{x})$ operator, then notices that $\langle \vec{p} | \hat{\phi_0}(\vec{x}) | 0 \rangle = e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}}$. Schwartz interprets this finding to mean that the operator $\hat{\phi_0}(\vec{x})$ must create a particle at position $\vec{x}$, since from single-particle quantum mechanics we know that $\langle \vec{x} | \vec{p} \rangle = e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}}.$ So it seems like Schwartz is certainly implicitly assuming that $| \vec{p} \rangle$ should satisfy certain properties that we know from single-particle quantum mechanics. Still, single-particle quantum mechanics is not typically relativistic, so I am left not totally certain of what $| \vec{p} \rangle$ is meant to mean here.)

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/343516/getting-particles-from-fields-normalization-issue-or-localization-issue).

Comment: Perhaps you would benefit from Chapters 2-5 of Weinberg's textbook. He first defines the one-particle states, then defines the Fock space, then defines the creation and annihilation operators and finally constructs fields. In the process he argues why quantum fields are the simpler way to implement cluster decomposition and Lorentz invariance.