# Field operators on vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, fourier-transform, vacuum

What do the field operators $\psi$ and $\pi$ produce when they act on vacuum $|0>$ state?
Here,

$$\psi(\vec{x}) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}\left(a_p e^{i\vec{p}\cdot \vec x} + a_p^\dagger e^{-i\vec p \cdot \vec x}\right) $$

and

$$\pi(\vec{x}) =   -i\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\sqrt{\frac{E_p}{2}}\left(a_p e^{i\vec p \cdot \vec x} - a_p^\dagger e^{-i\vec p \cdot \vec x}\right)$$

Comment: What $\pi |0>$ will give us? Can we say $\psi|0>$ will give us a particle at position x?

Comment: Yeah, it is clear now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definitions/conventions trivially yield
$$\psi(\vec{x})|0\rangle  = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{ 2E_p }   e^{-i\vec p \cdot \vec x} |\vec p\rangle $$
and
$$\pi(\vec{x})|0\rangle  =   \frac{i}{2}\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{3}}   e^{-i\vec p \cdot \vec x} | \vec p\rangle .$$
What is it you are seeking? These are wavepackets of one-particle states localized at x,  within basically a Compton wavelength *1/m*, as you might know. You may  appreciate [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/343516/getting-particles-from-fields-normalization-issue-or-localization-issue)  near-duplicate answer. P&S (2.35) define
$$
|\vec p\rangle\equiv \sqrt{2E_p} ~a_p^\dagger|0\rangle,\implies \\
\langle \vec p| \psi (\vec x)|0\rangle = e^{-i \vec p \cdot \vec x}.
$$